# How to make a UDP stream with a m3u8 source

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming

I'm trying to emit through UDP multicast a m3u8 stream, but I cannot find the solution because I have some special requeriments.

The device getting this UDP multicast streaming is a TV-headend that converts it into a COFDM mux (a DTT TV channel).
This damn device only accepts streamings with the exact speed as it needs to modulate it. For that, I need the -re flag.
Also, the m3u8 source, as usual, sends streaming splitted into chunks of several seconds.

Then, while ffmpeg receives the new URL, opens it, read contents, does his job... the image freezes a little.
Sometimes, audio and video desync.

So, I had one idea but cannot know i this is even possible.
This is, read all input stream as it comes (without -re option), but emit it at real time.
I read somewhere that there is no way to fix output "speed".
The "sad" thing is that using ffplay, the playback is fine. Maybe because it buffers the UDP streaming.

Another problem I have is that ffmpeg doesn't selects automatically the best quality of the streams. I need to use -map flag and other problems shows up with my beloved TV-Headend. Anyway, this is another question.

In short, how can I read input at full speed but emit it at a x1 speed as if command has the -re flag?

I'm using this command to stream

```
ffmpeg -re -i http://etbvnogeo-lh.akamaihd.net/i/ETBSTR1_1@595581/master.m3u8 -c:v copy -c:a copy -f mpegts udp://239.0.0.1:1234?pkt_size=1316
```

Comment: Do you require the solution to be real-time/live? Because if not, you might want to do it in separate steps. First, download the whole program via HLS, join it into a single video file, then UDP-stream that video file.

Comment: Thanks @Spiff Sadly yes. I need re-emit the live stream.